# inform http client about an error

Tags: c, linux, http, server

I'm implementing a simple http server (hw of a university course).

the implementation simply parses the client's request and sends a response (according to the given path - we treat it as a local file and send its content to the client).

my question is: how can I inform the client if an error occurred when trying to send data? specifically an error involving the client's socket.

obviously I can close the socket fd and exit from the server, but I need to let the client know that such error occurred.

code example:

```
char msg[BUF_SIZE];
strcpy(msg, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nthis is a message");
if (send(sockFd, msg, BUF_SIZE, 0) < 0)
{
    printf("send syscall failed: %s\nExiting...\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Most cases when you get an error from `send` you can't send anything at all, and so there is really no other way to inform the client that something went wrong than close the connection without sending anything at all (a good client will detect this case and display an error message to the user, and the user is most of the time not interested about the technical details about the error anyway).